# Increase number of maximum apache requests?

Tags: apache-2.2, max-requests

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Increasing the number of Apache requests?](https://serverfault.com/questions/78554/increasing-the-number-of-apache-requests)

I want to increase the number of max requests, currently it's limited to 150 and it's slowing down my server when it reached that.

Im on cPanel/WHM by the way.

Answer (score 1):

The configuration settings you are searching for are:

```
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
    StartServers          10
    MinSpareServers       10
    MaxSpareServers      30
    MaxClients          256
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>

<IfModule mpm_worker_module>
    StartServers          5
    MaxClients          200
    MinSpareThreads      25
    MaxSpareThreads      75
    ThreadsPerChild      25
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>
```

Look what Module you are using. Normally prefork is used.

I dont know cpanel, but most of these Configuration tools use templates. So you can just grep in the template directory of cpanel

```
grep -ri "MaxClients" /patch/to/cpanel
```

Or maybe you can insert custum setting to your apache somewhere in the Webinterface.
Also you can try to setup your apache by hand, and try if your Problems went away. Then if it works, try to adjust the cpanel thing.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a duplicate of https://serverfault.com/questions/78554/increasing-the-number-of-apache-requests. Please see my answer over there. Basically, you can't simply apply the changes evildead (or LapTop006 on the other question) are suggesting, they must be placed in `/usr/local/apache/conf/includes/pre_virtualhost_2.conf`